# How to convert URL cell text as small link when press on it open as URL?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

How to convert cell text as link when press on it open on URL browser on angular 7 ?

I have cell text for column offilneURL text inside cell display URL as text

I need to convert text or replace text with link then when press on it redirect to URL directly.

component.html

```
<tbody>
<ng-container *ngFor="let repcon of ReportControl">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let repdata of ReportData">
                    <tr *ngFor="let rep of reportdetailslist">

                      <td *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">


                        <span>


                          {{rep[coln]}}
                        </span>
                        <div *ngIf="coln==repcon.fieldName">
                          <div *ngIf="repcon.columnType==1">
                            display text as link url
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Sample data

```
RevisionId   offilneURL
122345       https://source.z2data.com/2019/1/13/8/55/47/351/662203977/21527_SPCN.PDF
             display text as link url
```

Above exactly current status of data
I Expected to be :

```
RevisionId   offilneURL
    122345       URL link
```

Small shortcut name when click on it redirects to link URL above.
I need to make as URL for two reason :

Firstly, it takes too much space.

Secondly, I can click link directly without copy and past URL browser.

**Updated**

to access url on every link by  {{rep.offilneURL}}

Can you tell me how to pass {{rep.offilneURL}} and open as url with short name
description

Comment: Using the `<a>` should works in this case. Try to do something like `<a [href]="yourURLVariableHere">Open</a>`

Comment: thank you for reply what you mean variable here

Comment: Something like 

`let myURL = 'https://google.com';` 

To show this as a link you can use `<a [href]="myURL">Open</a>`

Comment: can you please help me how to get variable have cell content in my url variable

Comment: You want to get cell content and open as a URL?

Comment: yes and display text on cell URL display as short name URL link not big

Comment: can you please help me according to my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no press origin event in js, but you can use click event instead, like dom.Click =function (e) {}. You can get the url text in the parameter e, and then call window.open (url) to jump

Comment: my url variable is  {{rep.offilneURL}} my question how to make it clickabe and with short string

Comment: it added link and it work but still plain text old exist so how to remove it